# Do I have to allocate everything on the heap (that gets stored within) heap containers?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, allocation

I'm overriding the new operator to manually allocate heap space when using the new keyword.

Usually using a stack-allocated heap container with pointers to its items-

```
CArray<CObject*> objects;
```

-is fine. but I'm picky and I want to make buffers-

```
CArray<CObject> objects;
```

-that let me modify POD types. So, I allocate them on the stack which is naturally suited for their use:

```
CVertex vertex;
objects.push_back(vertex);
```

But it corrupts the heap (I've had one of those bad weeks) and gives a crazy error:

```
0xC0000017: Not Enough Quota.
```

I pre-allocate the array objects and then use the = operator internally in **push_back()**.

I solved the problem by allocating the temporary objects on the heap and then adding them to the array. But it doesn't seem right, and I just don't get it.

As requested, some code:

```
CArray::push_back( T& newElement )
{
m_internalElements[allocatedSize] = newElement;
allocatedSize++;
}

CArray::preallocate_and_initialize( size_t itemCount )
{
T* newInternalElements = mem::allocate_and_initialize( T, itemCount );
//copy over
}
```

Note that it all works with heap allocated **CVertex**'s as I am using these objects in a binary search of the buffer elements (finding the right item in the index buffer for a given vertex) and it builds a mesh perfectly fine!

Comment: How can you allocate objects on the stack in operator= and expect them to live through the function? If they are, as soon as you leave that scope, they'll die and leave you with a dangling reference. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: hi zneak, they are pre-allocated with their constructors called, then the = operator copies the fields over from the stack instance before it goes out of scope.

Comment: Can you post the code to your version of `operator new` and `CArray::push_back`

Comment: Do you do bounds checking anywhere in `push_back()`? Another point, if it works with pointers, but not with stack-allocated objects, `CVertex::operator=` is probably the problem.

Comment: done :) the copy ctor is auto generated by msvc++ and it's a POD type:
vec4 Pos;
vec4 Normal;

I just double-checked the size of CVertex and it's sizeof(vec4)*2.

Comment: Hm, what about `mem::allocate_and_initialize`? What does it do exactly?

Comment: literally just calls __HeapAlloc16(pHeap, HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, objectSize); and then initializes by using the = operator copying over an empty T instance (to be safe).

Comment: Great, you could have mentioned that you're using special heap functions ... Do you use `HeapCreate()` or `GetProcessHeap()`? Or better yet, just show what the relevant `mem::` stuff does.

Comment: GetProcessHeap(); Sorry I'm new to this heap stuff!    mem::free does objectSize = __HeapSize16( mHeap, HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, objectPointer ); __HeapFree16(mHeap, HEAP_GENERATE_EXCEPTIONS, objectPointer);

Comment: yeah, I do bounds checking. Sorry also for the lack of code- it's commercial and I've had to make it simpler.

Comment: Can't you try to recreate the problem in a minimal compilable example? Thats what most people try to do.

Answer (score 1):

`0xC0000017` is `STATUS_NO_MEMORY`. I.e., you exhausted the virtual address space, i.e., you are using too much memory.

If you expect to have a lot of elements, reserving space before you call `push_back` repeatedly should be enough to avoid running out of memory. You can use `CArray::SetSize(0, itemCount)` to reserve space for all your elements.

Comment: Nope, that's why it was such a crazy error! I can allocate 2GB just before this happens :)

Comment: That's the limit of contiguous virtual memory you can allocate on Win32.

Answer (score 0):

CVertex is derived from CObject? You cant do that if CVertex has more instance data. (I mean you cannot create an array of CObjects and put CVertexes in it)
How big should the compiler make the slots in the CObject array, they will be CObject sized, then you will try to put something bigger in the slots -> bang

You should put boost::shared_ptr objects in your array. Once you have that idiom worked out you will never go back

Comment: yep, I explicitly use a CArray holding CVertex elements in this case. I don't use pointers because I need the data in a contiguous buffer to copy to a DirectX buffer :)